# How to bulk susbstitute _ by / in Windows filename for all files in a folder?

Tags: windows, powershell

The command I'm trying is:

```
Get-Children | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_','/' }
```

But apparently we can't substitute by `/` for file names in Windows. The error is:

> Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

Comment: You can't use a forward-slash in a Windows filename. It's just not permissible.

Comment: / is an invalid character for a filename, You cannot create a file with this character in it's name.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, what you want simply isn't possible in Windows. Forward slashes are [reserved characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions) that are not allowed in file and folder names.

> **Naming Conventions**
>
> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:
>
> […]
>
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - < (less than)
>     - > (greater than)
>     - : (colon)
>     - " (double quote)
>     - / (forward slash)
>     - \ (backslash)
>     - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - ? (question mark)
>     - * (asterisk)